# Cannot run psql in postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, psql

I am using Postgresql 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I receive the below error when I type `psql`:
a

> ```
> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
> ```

On checking the logs in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`, I see the error as:

> 2018-11-26 13:17:41 IST [3508-1] FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Below are the permissions of `etc/ssl/private` and `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` files:

```
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ ls -l /etc/ssl
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     20480 Nov 22 13:06 certs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     10835 Dec  8  2017 openssl.cnf
drwxr--r-- 2 root ssl-cert  4096 Nov 22 13:06 private

vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/ssl/private
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert 1704 Nov 22 13:06 ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in setting permissions?

**UPDATE #1**: `postgres` user is also added to the group `ssl-cert`.

```
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ getent group ssl-cert
ssl-cert:x:112:postgres
```

**UPDATE #2:** I found that there is no `server.key` present in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on "/etc/ssl/private" should be "drwx--x---" (aka "0710"), which should have been the permissions it came with.  I don't know it got changed.  You could restore it with:

```
sudo chmod 0710 /etc/ssl/private/
```

Although maybe there is also a way to do it with your package manager.

You don't need a server.key file in "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main", because postgresql is configured to look for it in "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" instead.  You can make or get your own cert and put in "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main", but then you will have to change the configuration to look for it there.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for the info.. I would better prefer to keep it to refer to `snakeoil.key` instead then.  Also, I ran your command both with and without `-R`. With `-R`, it tells me `private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access
2018-11-26 18:55:21 IST [14299-2] DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.`  Without `-R`, it tells me `could not load private key file`.

Comment: I did restart the service using `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Comment: I don't understand that one.  The file itself is owned by root and **does** have 0640 or less (or at least it did at the time you showed it to us--maybe it change since then).  After you ran chmod with -R, what did you do to undo that?

Comment: It didn't understand it either. Also, I first did without `-R` and then with `-R`. This way, the snakeoil permission was not tampered. Anyways, I got an answer on SO and I just realized that the permission  for `ssl-cert` had to `5` instead of `4` and `0` for others. That's what the answer I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477604/cannot-run-psql-in-postgresql-9-5/) does. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

1. View detail log and change permission to 0600. It work with me

DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.